# Android Jetpack WorkManager - Test UniquePeriodicWork Execution

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am using Android's [Jetpack WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to schedule some periodic download tasks once a day. I followed the instructions and get a `Success` back when the Work is enqueued:

```
val work = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UpdateWorker>(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setConstraints(constraints) // Internet connection, idle and battery not low
            .addTag("ANNOUNCEMENTS_WORKER_TAG")
            .build()

val workOperation = workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("UPDATE_WORK_TAG", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, work)

workOperation.state.observe(this, Observer { state ->
    Timber.d("state: $state") // is successful
})
```

How do I now know that this is really happening? How can I (unit) test the repeating execution of my task?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write instrumentation tests on a WorkManager:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class UpdateWorkerTest{

    private lateinit var context: Context

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    }

    @Test
    fun testWorkerCall() {
        val yourWorker = TestListenableWorkerBuilder<UpdateWorker>(context).build()
        runBlocking {
            val result = yourWorker.doWork()
            assertThat(result, `is`(ListenableWorker.Result.success()))
        }
    }

}
```

> How do I now know that this is really happening

You have to trust the Google team for that and hope you don't have a One Plus device.

For your own concern you can just play a little with your device, perhaps turn it off and then on and then wait until the jobs run (run logs on the console), etc.

There is more about testing in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing-210)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the WorkManager testing library to unit test your Workers.  Include it by following the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#declaring_dependencies

The overview docs for the package may be helpful for you: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/package-summary

You can see some sample usage here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/WorkManagerSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/background/ImageOperationsTest.kt

Comment: Thanks for your answer and efforts! But this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to test the task of my Worker, I want to test my Worker's periodical execution over time. So will my worker really gets triggered every day?

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind that the interval you're setting is the minimum period between two following execution of your Worker. WorkManager it's going to shift the execution to respect constraints and battery policies (doze mode, etc.).  The end result is that your worker's execution time is going to shift (first execution at 6:00AM, next one at 6:21AM, then at 6:34AM, etc).  This is explained in the [PeriodicWorkRequest reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.html).

Once you've enqueued your WorkRequest you can observe it's status using a LiveData (from the [Operation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Operation.html) object like you're doing or requesting a WorkInfo with [`getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(java.lang.String)). In this way you can get the status update for your WorkRequest (`BLOCKED` --> `ENQUEUED` --> `RUNNING` --> `SUCCEDED`/`FAILED` and at any point the status can transition to `CANCELLED`).

[You can get more information on how to observe your WorkRequest status on this blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-basics-beba51e94048).

Comment: Thanks for your valid answer. But my question was more pointed at Unit Testing my once a day Worker. I already subscribed via LiveData to the Operation, but this doesn't help me to validate the "every 24h execution". So the questions is: Will my worker really gets triggered every day?

Answer (score 0):

Dude you must test your code not WorkManager Framework. so you must create a method like this in your code:

```
val ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 86400000‬

fun createWorker() : WorkRequest {

    val work = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<SendDataWorker>(ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setConstraints(constraints) // Internet connection, idle and battery not low
            .addTag("ANNOUNCEMENTS_WORKER_TAG")
            .build()
}
```

and write a test method for test it:

```
val work = createPeriodicWorkRequest()
assertEquals(work.workSpec.intervalDuration, ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS)
```

Comment: whats the implementation of createPeriodicWorkRequest() ?

Answer (score -1):

As you can read in the [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) the **WorkManager** is an API that ensure the execution if all the constraints are met. A constraint could be setup by you - like "has internet connection"-, but you should also have in mind that the OS has his own constraints - like "not be in Doze mode"-.

If any of the constraint is not met, the API will try again in the next period of time.

In a nutshell and as google says:

*"WorkManager is intended for tasks that are **deferrable**—that is, not required to run immediately—and required to **run reliably** even if the app exits or the device restarts."*

So the API doesn't ensure you to run the code at the exact time, but ensure you to be executed as soon as possible, having always in mind the constraints and the repeat interval.

That means that you don't need to test it, but the code inside the Worker. In the same way you don't need to test if the "onResume" method has been called in an Activity if it's on top.